# What are Indikativ, Konjunktiv I, Konjunktiv II of any verb like unternehmen?

Tags: verb, conjugation

Could anyone explain them for me?
Why does every verb has those three different conjugations?

Comment: What is your native language?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- **Indikativ**
  You use this mode when you want to tell facts. You say what really is.

  > Wir ***unternehmen*** einen Ausflug.
  >   We make a trip.

  This means: We really do it. This is no phantasy. It is fact. And it is not a quote of someone else. We say it.
- **Konjunktiv I**
  When you repeat something that you have heard, you can use direct or indirect speech. Direct speech means quoting exactly what was said:

  > Kurt hat mir am Telefon gesagt: »Wir unternehmen einen Ausflug.«
  >   Kurt said to me on the phone: "We make a trip."

  In indirect speech you need Konjunktiv I:

  > Kurt hat mir am Telefon gesagt, er ***unternehme*** einen Ausflug.

  You can transform this in a sub-clause beginning with "dass" with Indikative instead of Konjunktiv I, without changing the meaning:

  > Kurt hat mir am Telefon gesagt, dass er einen Ausflug unternimmt.
  >   Kurt told me on the phone that he makes a trip.
- **Konjuktiv II**
  You use this to describe irreal phantasies:

  > Ach, wäre es nicht schön, wenn wir einen Ausflug **unternähmen**?
  >   Oh, wouldn't it be nice to make a trip?

  You are not making a trip, nor are you really planning to make some. You are just dreaming of something that probably never will happen.

---

There is another mode beside Indikativ and Konjunktiv:

- **Imperativ**
  You use this mode for commands:

  > Unternimm einen Ausflug!
  >   Make a trip!

---

You can use this modes in even more situations. But I understood your question in that way, that you have no idea what they are good for. I hope, now you know. Your grammar book will tell you much more usages.

Comment: Thank you so much that has aboslutely made it easier for me
do you recommend a specific grammar book?

Comment: There is a [follow-up question on one of the examples](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/48725/2594).

Comment: I strongly object to the proposition that a *dass*-clause in *Indikativ* is equivalent to *Konjunktiv I* in a main clause. If you say "Er sagte am Telefon, dass er einen Ausflug *unternimmt*", you present it as a matter of fact that he's actually going on the trip – like if you know it for sure. If you say "Er sagte am Telefon, dass er einen Ausflug *unternehme*", you leave it open whether the trip is undertaken, you just give an account of his statement.

Answer (score 0):

There are three basic conjugations, these are *Präsens Indikativ*, *Präsens Konjunktiv I* and *Präteritum*. *Konjunktiv II* uses the same forms as *Präteritum*, apart from auxiliaries, modal verbs and some few irregular verbs. All other mood (apart from the imperative) and time forms are built with auxiliaries.

The conjugation of *unternehmen* is the same as for *nehmen*:

> **Präsens Indikativ:**
> ich nehme, du nimmst, er/sie/es nimmt, wir/sie nehmen, ihr nehmt
>
> **Präsens Konjunktiv I:**
> ich nähme, du nähmst, er/sie/es nähme, wir/sie nähmen, ihr nähmt
>
> **Präteritum:**
> ich nahm, du nahmst, er/sie/es nahm, wir/sie nahmen, ihr nahmt

As you can see, *nehmen* is a strong verb, which means its conjugation follows the *Ablaut* pattern. The other common pattern is the *-te-* of the weak verbs, e.g. *kaufen*:

> **Präsens Indikativ:**
> ich kaufte, du kaufst, er/sie/es kauft, wir/sie kaufen, ihr kauft
>
> **Präsens Konjunktiv I:**
> ich kaufe, du kauftest, er/sie/es kaufe, wir/sie kauften, ihr kauftet
>
> **Präteritum:**
> ich kaufte, du kauftest, er/sie/es kaufte, wir/sie kauften, ihr kauftet

Of course there are irregular verbs, but the most verbs fall into one of those two groups, so you only have to learn those two patterns each with 15 forms apart from the few irregulars.

Comment: Thank you for your help,i now understood the differences between them :)