# Translation of indirect speech in English

Tags: german-to-english, tense, grammar-identification, indirect-speech

- Direct speech:

  > Kurt hat mir am Telefon gesagt: »Wir unternehmen einen Ausflug.«
- Indirect speech:

  > Kurt hat mir am Telefon gesagt, er **unternehme** einen Ausflug.
  >   Kurt hat mir am Telefon gesagt, dass er einen Ausflug unternimmt.
- English translation of indirect speech:

  > Kurt told me on the phone that *he makes a trip.*

The above sentences I took from the [this post](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/43196).

My question is about given English translation: “he makes a trip.” I generally see if the reporting verb *(gesagt)* is in past tense, then the present tenses of the direct are changed into the corresponding past tense, for example:

> Hans sagte, er sei 30 Jahre alt.
>   Hans said he **was** 30 years old.

However, the given English translation is in present tense; why is it?

Answer (score 3):

The grammatical phenomenon in question is called ***[backshifting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_of_tenses#English)***. For reported speech, it means that the tense of what is reported is dictated by frame of the reporter (who tells that something was spoken) and not in the frame of the speaker. For instance, if like in your example the report happens in the past, the tense of the report shifts back one step (as compared to direct speech). **English has this for reported speech; German doesn’t.** In German, the tense of reported speech is dictated by the frame of the speaker.

Thus, the correct translation of your example would be:

> Kurt told me on the phone that he **made** a trip.

Since this difference in backshifting is not very prominent in real life and teaching English as a foreign language, many native speakers of German do not know about it, let alone apply it correctly all the time.
As the author of your example was a native speaker of German, I assume he just made a mistake.

---

For fun and another example, we can look at the English sentence in question:

> Kurt told me on the phone that he makes a trip.

First let’s ignore for the sake of the example that *makes* may refer to the future (of reporter’s frame) and that you probably would rather say something like:

> Kurt told me on the phone that he was going to make a trip

Due to backshifting, *makes* in the example means that the trip alleged by Kurt happens now (in the time frame of the reporter), and thus after Kurt has told the reporter on the phone. An example containing all this information with direct speech would be:

> Kurt hat mir am Telefon gesagt: »Wir werden am Dienstag einen Ausflug unternehmen.« Heute ist Dienstag.

… and with indirect speech (using the subjunctive I of the future):

> Kurt hat mir am Telefon gesagt, er werde **heute** einen Ausflug unternehmen.

Note that in German we need additional references to capture the exact point in the future (from the speaker’s time frame). Otherwise the trip could happen at any point after the phone conversation: before, simultaneously or after the time frame of the reporter.

Comment: +1 Es ist schon einmal eine tolle Leistung, das Problem des Fragestellers erkannt zu haben! Aber *He makes a trip* ist doch Quatsch. Auf Englisch würde es heißen: *He is going to make a trip. He said he was going to make a trip.* Es sei denn, es handelt sich um eine Gewohnheit, dann wäre es: *He makes that trip every day. He said that he makes that trip every day*.

Comment: @DavidVogt: *Aber* He makes a trip *ist doch Quatsch.* – So hart würde ich das nicht sehen (aber das ist dann wirklich eine Frage für [english.se])), aber Du hast Recht, dass es nicht sehr idiomatisch ist (worauf ich jetzt hinweise).

Comment: Die wichtige Erkenntnis ist, daß es im Englischen *backshift* gibt und im Deutschen nicht. Das kommt klar rüber. Was ich noch nicht ganz verstehe: Was ist denn die direkte Form von *Kurt told me on the phone that he makes a trip*? Bei Formen wie *I will make a trip, I am going to make a trip, I am making a trip, I may make a trip* is klar, wie sie *backshifted* aussehen. Aber wenn Kurt das Präsens benutzt haben sollte, um über die Zukunft zu sprechen, dann wäre das doch einer der wenigen Fälle, wo es **keinen** *backshift* gibt?

Comment: @DavidVogt: Erstmal redest Du gerade von der indirekten Rede. Die Zeitform *makes* ist also nicht notwendigerweise diejenige, die Kurt benutzt. So oder so wird es kompliziert und hängt davon ab, wie weit in die Zukunft die jeweilige Aussage reicht.

Comment: Was kann Kurt denn außer *makes* benutzen, damit bei der Wiedergabe *He said he makes the trip* herauskommt?

Comment: @DavidVogt: Zum Beispiel: “I will make a trip”.

Comment: Aber dann käme doch *that he would make a trip* heraus? (Oder *backshift* unterbleibt?)

Comment: Normalerweise ja, aber da mit sind wir wieder [hier](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/48725/translation-of-indirect-speech-in-english/48744?noredirect=1#comment118757_48744) angelangt.

Answer (score 0):

You may use **both** present and past tense for the reporting verb. It all depends on what you want to convey. Be careful about the perfect tenses. Unlike almost all other situations, German *Perfekt* is in the present here:

> Hans **sagt**, er *sei* 30 Jahre alt.
>
> Hans **hat gesagt**, er *sei* 30 Jahre alt.

Hans is right next to me. He cannot talk German to you, so I translate what he **just said**, as it was the present. The reported speech for Hans' direct speech “I am 30 years old.” has to be in *Konjunktiv I* nevertheless.

> Hans **sagte**, er *sei* 30 Jahre alt.
>
> Hans **hatte gesagt**, er *sei* 30 Jahre alt.

Hans **said** this a while ago. The reported speech for Hans' direct speech “I am 30 years old.” has to be in *Konjunktiv I* still.

Of course, if you wrote a story, the main tense is past tense, so you can only use that one.

---

*Sorry about the mess. Unlike English, the use of German tenses doesn't follow strict combination rules but semantics. It's the greatest struggle for German speakers when they learn English. We always use and combine English tenses wrong, though the English rules are simple. Simple rules are an alien concept to German speakers.*

Comment: I have one another doubt. Can I use sie instead of er like "sie unternehmen einen Ausflug.?

Comment: Which *sie*? A group or *formal you*?

Comment: A group (they) not a formal you.

Comment: *Hans sagt, sie unternähmen einen Ausflug* – Hans is right next to me. He cannot talk German to you so I translate what he just said: “We go/are on a trip.”

Comment: This verb *unternehmen* in indirect speech is tricky itself. It's a *sein*, *tun* or *machen* in disguise. Very elaborated code. If you talk like this, people expect you to have an *excellent* command of German.

Comment: Can't we say "they are on a trip." ?

Comment: That's just the same sentence. Context is key. Without any clue about another group, people would assume Hans is talking about his own group for the sake of keeping things as simple as possible.

Comment: Na ja, "Hans hat gesagt" kann sich genauso auf eine Aussage beziehen, die schon eine Weile zurückliegt. Ich würde den Perfekt nicht als Ausdruck des Präsens beschreiben, sondern eher betonen, dass der Perfekt auch die unmittelbare Vergangenheit miteinschließt.

Comment: Es liegt irgendwo zwischen Vergangenheit und Gegenwart. Wie ich ja schrieb, sind die Regeln zur Verwendung der Zeitformen im Deutschen wenig strikt. Das verwirrt Englischsprecher meiner Erfahrung nach am meisten.

Comment: The question is about the tense of the reported speech, yet you focus of the tense of the inquit.

Comment: I focus on the fact that German, unlike English, does not arrange tenses as orderly. It makes no sense to talk about only about the tense of reported speech or the tense tense of the report verb. You always have to talk about both. That's what I did in my answer.